# MySQL Conditional Transaction

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

Having trouble figuring out what is possible in MySQL (so many internet searches return T-SQL answers).  I need to execute a transaction where a set of values are updated if where clause is satisfied for a particular status.  Otherwise if either the select is empty or its the wrong status return.  e.g.

```
Start;

If select from table where status is not done
    then update to done
else if status done
    return id
else 
    return empty set

Commit;
```

That may be rough psuedo code but essentially what i'm trying to do.  Right now I'm breaking this up and handling it server side and know the pitfalls of that vs letting the database handle it.

Comment: Is this a stored procedure?

Comment: No, not at the moment.  I build the SQL statement server side.

Comment: You can't do that sort of thing in a single statement, so your options are to do this in application code, or to do it in a stored procedure.

Comment: Currently I'm doing it in the application code.  If that's truly the case then glad I asked the question otherwise I'd continue to spend more time testing ideas.

Comment: @tadman moved to stored procedure, not sure why i hesitant, thanks for the reminder!

Comment: If you got it working it's worth adding an answer to expain and help others.